# awaited Promises still returning <pending>

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise

I have an array of data objects about people. Each person object includes 0-n URLs for additional info (guests of the person).

I want to process this list, calling each of the 'guest' URLs and including the guest's names in the original data set.

Context: this is an AWS lambda function. I'm using [lambda-local](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-local) to run this locally. (`lambda-local -l index.js -e fixtures/test_event1.json`).

I'm successfully using await/async to retrieve the initial set of data.

But I'm unable to get if working for these further calls about guest info. It always shows a pending Promise, even though the result is awaited.

```
// index.js

const fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.handler = async function(event){

    try {
        let registrations = await getEventRegistrations();
        console.log(registrations);

/* All good here - sample console output
[ { contactId: 43452967,
    displayName: 'aaa, bbb',
    numGuests: 0,
    guestUrls: [] },
  { contactId: 43766365,
    displayName: 'bbb, ccc',
    numGuests: 1,
    guestUrls:
     [ 'https://<URL>' ] },
  { contactId: 43766359,
    displayName: 'ccc, ddd',
    numGuests: 2,
    guestUrls:
     [ 'https://<URL>',
       'https://<URL> ] } ]
*/

        // Expanding the guest URLs is proving problematic - see expandGuests function below
        registrations = registrations.map(expandGuests);
        console.log(registrations);


/* Registrations are just pending Promises here, not the real data

[ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]

*/

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(registrations),
        };
    }
    catch (exception) {
        console.log(exception);
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: 'Unable to retrieve data.'
        };
    }
};

function getEventRegistrations() {
    return fetch('<URL>')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Event registrants request failed', error);
        return null;
    });
}

function getGuestName(url) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(guest => guest.DisplayName)
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Guest name request failed', error);
        return null;
    });
}

async function expandGuests(data) {

    const promises = data.guestUrls.map(url => getGuestName(url));
    data.guestNames = await Promise.all(promises);

    return data;
}
```

How can I resolve these pending Promises and thus return useful data?

Thank you.

Comment: You can not. Promises are kind of infectious. If a function uses them every function using that function has to use them. That's how asynchronous code works in is.

Comment: EVERY `async` function returns a promise.  That's how they work.  So, you will have to use `.then()` or `await` on your `async` function call to get its final resolved value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments are correct in pointing out that mapping an `async` function will return an array of Promises. What they don't explicitly mention is that you have two maps, and which one is problematic.

The issue is in the line:

```
reservations = reservations.map(expandGuests);
```

Any time you use map, you'll need to actually resolve the promises that return.

So:

```
const mappedPromises = reservations.map(expandGuests);  //returns an Array of Pending promises
const mappedReservations = await Promise.all(mappedPromises);  //resolves the promises
```

Comment: YES! Thank you. This solved it. It's obvious the other answer was accurate now, but only this insight finally shone the light in the right place.

Answer (score 6):

array.map doesn't contain any logic to wait for promises. It just calls the function for each element of the array, and then synchronously produces an array of the results. If you pass in async functions, then the result be an array of promises (since all async functions return promises).

You'll need to use `Promise.all` to create a promise which will resolve once all the individual promises have resolved, and then `await` that.

```
const promises = data.guestUrls.map(url => getGuestName(url));
data.guestNames = await Promise.all(promises);
```

---

P.S, i strongly recommend against mixing async/await with .then. The cases where you actually need to do so are very rare, so most of the time you just make the code harder to understand. For example, this function:

```
async function getGuestName(url) {
    return await fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(guest => guest.DisplayName)
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Guest name request failed', error);
        return null;
    });
}
```

Should either be done like this:

```
async function getGuestName(url) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const guest = await res.json();
    return guest.DisplayName;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Guest name request failed', error);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Or like this

```
 function getGuestName(url) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(guest => guest.DisplayName)
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Guest name request failed', error);
        return null;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

Changing the `expandGuests` function to:

`
async function expandGuests(data) {

    const promises = data.guestUrls.map(url => getGuestName(url));
    data.guestNames = await Promise.all(promises);

    return data;
}
`

results in an output of

`
[ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]
`

(from a `console.log(registrations)` call after `registrations = registrations.map(expandGuests);`)

Comment: Thank you again @nicholas-tower. The additional 'ps' points are really helpful too and now implemented.